# Finding the state space representation of a dynamic model with the force and angle as control inputs vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, torque

I am trying to design a controller to control the angle of the force on my mobile rigid body. I some questions:

1. I am not sure how to write the state space representation with the force, $F$ and angle, $θ$ as my control input. State vector should be $x,\,y,\,ψ,\,\dot x,\, ̇y,\, \dot ψ$. I started by finding the total force and torque on the center of mass in the inertial frame, $M$. I have 4 forces one on each corner of my mobile rigid body with different angles ranging from 0 to 360 degrees but I didn't draw them because it would look messy.

[image]

[image]

2. But I don't know how to write the equations so that $θ$  can be multiplied since $θ$ is in cos or sin. So I am guessing that I have to find the torque, $\tau = I \ddot θ$. I am having a problem finding it.

Comment: You want your force to be oriented relative to the body, or the world?

Comment: What is $b_{X_{BL}}$, $b_{Y_{BL}}$ and $b_{\psi_{BL}}$?

Comment: I dont understand the question. The equations in the body frame are $$ \begin{aligned} \ddot{x}_{BL} & = \frac{1}{m} ( x_T \cos \theta ) \\ \ddot{y}_{BL} &= \frac{1}{m} ( x_T \sin \theta ) \\ \ddot{\psi} & = \frac{1}{I} \left( \frac{\ell}{2} x_T \sin\theta - \frac{w}{2} x_T \cos\theta \right) \end{aligned} $$ I don't see any cross or velocity bias terms because all the quantities are resolved onto the CM.

Comment: @ja72 "You want your force to be oriented relative to the body, or the world?" I think its relative to the body but in the inertial frame, M. Because I want to do some numerical integration to solve later.

Comment: @ja72  "What is bXBL, bYBL and bψBL?" It is the linear and rotational viscous damping (resists velocity in those directions).

Comment: @ja72 "I dont understand the question" I am trying to write [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGZQg.png

Comment: Sorry the above comment is incomplete because I didn't know you could only edit comments for 5 min and I don't know how to add a photo or equations to the comments

Comment: @ja72 "I dont understand the question" I am trying to write the state space representation of my dynamic model (shown in the link). u(t) is the control input vector, which I want to be force and angle. But since your suppose to multiply the control input vector to your control input matrix, I don't see how I could do that since my angle in my dynamic model is within sin and cos and not multiplied. I think this suggests I need another equation in the form of my angle but I'm not sure what it is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGZQg.png

Comment: @ja72 "I don't see any cross or velocity bias terms because all the quantities are resolved onto the CM" I used cross product to find the torque at CM so I wouldn't have to change my equations if my force angle is at 90, 180, 270 degrees. Plus I have 4 forces, one on each corner, sorry I didn't draw those because I thought it would be a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the general control force vector $\pmatrix{x_{T} & y_{T} & 0}$ along the angle $\theta$ (as shown above) and torque $\pmatrix{0 & 0 & \tau}$. Now resolve the equations of motion along the body, and at the center of mass.

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \ddot{x}_{BL} &= \frac{1}{m} \left( x_T \cos \theta - y_T \sin \theta \right) \\
  \ddot{y}_{BL} &= \frac{1}{m} \left( x_T \sin \theta + y_T \cos \theta \right) \\
  \ddot{\psi} & = \frac{1}{I} \left(\tau+ ( \frac{\ell}{2} y_T - \frac{w}{2} x_T ) \cos\theta + (\frac{\ell}{2} x_T + \frac{w}{2} y_T) \sin\theta \right)
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: I am trying to write the state space representation of my dynamic model. Read my comments to you questions above, thanks!

Comment: I need the control input vector to look like this u(t)=$\pmatrix{F_{T_{1-4}} &  \theta_{1-4 }}$ not $\pmatrix{x_{T} &  y_{T} & 0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 0 &  \tau}$

Comment: I am new at this and maybe this is an easy question but I am guessing its not possible to have theta be one of my control input vectors since no answers were in that form. I would use torque instead of theta if this was a dynamic model for a quad drone or propeller but I need the force to stop at a certain angle theta. Not continuously rotate in one direction.

Comment: So your problem is that the angle $\theta$ enters into the EOM as a non-linear fashion and cannot be used in a matrix/vector form. To solve this problem, convert the force and angle, into two perpendicular forces along and across the body to be used in the control vector.

Comment: Yes that is exactly my problem but your solution I still don't see how it would take theta out of cos or sin.

Comment: Replace the polar coordinate definition with a cartesian definition. In the equations above set $\theta=0$ and have $x_T$ and $y_T$ as control variables.